# Assignment by group in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the following data:

```
data <- data.table(ID = 1:10, x = c(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1), y = c(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1))
```

I want to assign the following value in a column `new`: For each pair of `x` and `y` (e.g. `x` = 1 and `y` = 1), find the row highest up in the list where this specific pair occurs and let  `new` be the `ID` of this row. For example, for all rows where `x` = 1 and `y` = 1, I want to `new` to be 6.

The following line of code seems to do precisely that:

```
data[, new := head(.SD, 1), .(x, y)]
```

My question is just, why does this work? `head(.SD, 1)` will be a list containing one row, how can R know I want to assign specifically the value in the first column of `head(.SD, 1)` to `new`? I was expecting an error when trying to run this code, but I do actually get the desired output.

Comment: it seems like when there is `by` argument, the safety check of `Supplied m items to be assigned to k items of column 'new'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.` is not reached. And *I think* that when only 1 column `new` is desired, elements enough to fill 1 column is take from the RHS output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very interesting observation.

First, I want to clarify that when you do `by = .(x, y)`, your `.SD` consists of only one column (`ID`). You can test that by comparing these two lines of code below.

This first line asks for the first column of `.SD`, and it works:

```
data[, head(.SD[, 1]), .(x, y)]
```

```
    x y ID
 1: 1 0  1
 2: 1 0  2
 3: 0 1  3
 4: 0 1  4
 5: 0 1  5
 6: 0 1  9
 7: 1 1  6
 8: 1 1  7
 9: 1 1 10
10: 0 0  8
```

But the second line below asks for the second column of `.SD` and it gets an error:

```
data[, head(.SD[, 2]), .(x, y)]
```

```
Error in `[.data.table`(.SD, , 2) : 
  Item 1 of j is 2 which is outside the column number range [1,ncol=1]
```

You see, `.SD` has only one column (`ID`). It does not contain the columns in `by`. That's why your code works as expected.

However, your observation is still valid. Consider the expanded `data.table` with two columns beside `x` and `y`.

```
data <- data.table(ID1 = 1:10, 
                   ID2 = letters[1:10],
                   x = c(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1),
                   y = c(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1))
data[, new := head(.SD, 1), .(x, y)]
data
```

```
    ID1 ID2 x y new
 1:   1   a 1 0   1
 2:   2   b 1 0   1
 3:   3   c 0 1   3
 4:   4   d 0 1   3
 5:   5   e 0 1   3
 6:   6   f 1 1   6
 7:   7   g 1 1   6
 8:   8   h 0 0   8
 9:   9   i 0 1   3
10:  10   j 1 1   6
```

`new` takes `ID1` only. Why? According to the help page of `:=`, when there is a type mismatch between the LHS and the RHS of `:=`, *"the RHS is coerced to match type of the LHS"*. In this case the RHS is a list of 3, and the LHS is a list of 1, so only the first element is taken.